# Ignoring "gem-name" because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine "gem-name" when I do bin/server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rbenv

Well, I've just changed rvm to rbenv, it seems to be installed right, bun when I do bin/server it gives me these errors:

```
20:14:58 web.1  | started with pid 7619

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring bcrypt-3.1.10 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine bcrypt --version 3.1.10

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring binding_of_caller-0.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine binding_of_caller --version 0.7.2

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring byebug-8.2.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 8.2.4

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring byebug-3.1.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 3.1.2

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring capybara-webkit-1.3.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine capybara-webkit --version 1.3.1

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring debug_inspector-0.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine debug_inspector --version 0.0.2

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring fast_stack-0.1.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine fast_stack --version 0.1.0

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.7.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.7.2

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring pg-0.18.4 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.18.4

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring pg-0.17.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine pg --version 0.17.1

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring puma-2.14.0 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine puma --version 2.14.0

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring stackprof-0.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine stackprof --version 0.2.7

20:14:58 web.1  | Ignoring therubyracer-0.12.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine therubyracer --version 0.12.1

20:14:59 web.1  | /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.12.3/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:373:in `block in replace_bin_path': can't find executable bundle (Gem::Exception)

20:14:59 web.1  |       from /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems.rb:278:in `activate_bin_path'

20:14:59 web.1  |       from /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/bundle:22:in `<main>'

20:14:59 web.1  | exited with code 1

20:14:59 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
```

It worked well when I used the same command bin/server with rvm.

If I do rails server, it offers me to start new rails application, however, i'm already in rails application, which was created and worked when i used rvm.
If I create new rails app, rails server works well. 
I've tried to do gem pristine --all, but it didn't help. I also tried to reinstall bundler, it didn't help as well. I suspect there may be something wrong with paths, but I changed them according to instructions.

RubyGems Environment:

```
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.6.4
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.0 (2015-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/jakov/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/jakov/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/jakov/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
     - /home/jakov/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
...
```

Is it normal that there are two of Gem paths? If not, how to fix it? 
This is my .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
if [ -d $HOME/.rbenv ]; then
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
fi

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"

# Add RVM to PATH for scripting
# Until LinuxBrew is fixed, the following is required.
# See: https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/issues/47
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/usr/lib64/pkgconfig:/usr/share/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
## Setup linux brew
export LINUXBREWHOME=$HOME/.linuxbrew
export PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/bin:$PATH
export MANPATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/man:$MANPATH
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/lib64/pkgconfig:$LINUXBREWHOME/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LINUXBREWHOME/lib64:$LINUXBREWHOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I can't continue my project because of these problems :c please, help, if you know how! 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Well, there was a config file in .bundle folder which should be deleted.And I also reinstalled rails gem. Now it works.